# How Can I put information in a outputstream from tapestry5?

Tags: java, servlets, tapestry

How Can I put information in a outputstream from tapestry5 ?

I need a page when a user enters it open a dialog for save or open the file with the outputstream information.

I write the next code:

public class Index {

```
@Inject
private RequestGlobals requestGlobals;

@OnEvent("activate")
public void onActivate() {
    try {
        HttpServletResponse response = requestGlobals.getHTTPServletResponse();
        response.setContentType("text/txt");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("hellooooooo");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Index.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

I hope that the result is only "helloooooooo" but is ("helloooooooo" + my html raw page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should have a return type of StreamResponse. You return an implementation of the interface StreamResponse, which simply returns the data you want with the content type you want.

Look it up here:

http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/

more info here:

http://tapestry.formos.com/nightly/tapestry5/tapestry-core/guide/pagenav.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with large response streams, using [StreamResponse](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/StreamResponse.html) can be somewhat inconvenient and inefficient (because you have to return an [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)). Better would be to write response directly to [OutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).

Fortunately, in Tapestry Wiki, there is a page for solving exactly this: [Tapestry5: How To Create A Component Event Result Processor](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToCreateAComponentEventResultProcessor).

Comment: This solution is the best if you want to avoid to write your file on the server side before sending it to the client. But the solution on Tapestry example need a fix : the closing of the `OutputStream` must be done in the `finally` block. We can also use `IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);` (from apache) to close the `OutputStream` without the need of a try...catch.

Comment: It is done in `finally` block. In fact, it is done twice: in `try` block and in `finally` block (just finally block is enough).